# Where's sqlite database file located in ionic 2 cordova

Tags: android, angular, sqlite, cordova, ionic2

I'm working with **cordova-plugin-sqlite** in angular2 ionic2. But I didn't find database file anywhere. I' have seen many questions regarding this issue but none of them helped me. It is not present in **www** folder. I want to know this .db file lies exactly and how to set location of this file.

```
this.sqlite.create(
{
    name: "MyDatabase.db", // <---- I want to know location of this file
    location: "default"    // and how to set its location
});
```

Comment: Did you get answer for this?

Comment: @AshutoshSingh no....

Comment: ok suppose if i want to get download the file (MyDatabase.db) , then how to get download it in ionic...  i mean, does something like : `.getLocation('default')` will give the path?

Comment: No idea bro... @AshutoshSingh

Answer (score 0):

The location for your db would be:

```
/data/data/<your package name ex: com.rajeev.myapp>/databases/MyDatabase.db
```

You can view the file in android studio from "**Device File Explorer**"